# MySQL snafoo with GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, group-concat

This works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT HEX(group_uuid) AS hexid 
FROM schema.table

>9B3D8DE01E1E049DA9F17D42B324AA66
>CDF112D740CE14EA08CA90E3C937DE8D
```

as does this

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT('\'', HEX(group_uuid), '\' ') AS hexid 
FROM schema.table

>'9B3D8DE01E1E049DA9F17D42B324AA66','9B3D8DE01E1E049DA9F17D42B324AA66' [etc...]
```

and this

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT HEX(group_uuid) SEPARATOR '\' ') AS hexid 
FROM schema.table

>9B3D8DE01E1E049DA9F17D42B324AA66' CDF112D740CE14EA08CA90E3C937DE8D
```

this, however,

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT('\'', DISTINCT HEX(group_uuid), '\' ') AS hexid 
FROM schema.table 

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; INSERT COIN
```

does not.

Is there some kind 'PREFIX' keyword that can be substituted or another syntax I'm supposed to follow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for

```
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('\'',HEX(group_uuid),'\'') SEPARATOR ' ')
```